# Actionscript 2.0 to 3.0, please give a hand, am I converting wrong?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm doing the Actionscript 2.0 to 3.0 work but I have very few idea on 3.0, Can somebody good guys help to make a translate please!
  I have try to finish a version but my work just cannot being "drag n drop" after changing the codes.

```
stop();
var randomPositionFrame = int(Math.random()*9)+1;
content_mc.gotoAndStop(randomPositionFrame);
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i)._alpha = 0;
eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).onPress = function(){
    if(this._currentframe == 1){
        this.startDrag();
    }
}
eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).onRelease = onMouseUp = function(){
    this.stopDrag();
}

eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i)._alpha = 0;
eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).onPress = function(){
    if(this._currentframe == 1){
        this.startDrag();
    }
}
eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).onRelease = onMouseUp = function(){
    this.stopDrag();
}
}

var winGame = false;
var alphaSpeed = 20;
var mouseListener:Object = new Object();
mouseListener.onMouseDown = function () { this.isDown = true;};
mouseListener.onMouseUp = function () {
this.isDown = false;
//Game Logic Check Correct
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    //term match description
    if(eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).mc._currentframe == 2 && eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).mc._currentframe == 2){
        if(eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i)._currentframe == 1){
            eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).gotoAndPlay(2);
            eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
    }
    //description match term
    else if(eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).mc._currentframe == 2 && eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).mc._currentframe == 2){
        if(eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i)._currentframe == 1){
            eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).gotoAndPlay(2);
            eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
    }
}
```

};
    Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);

```
this.onEnterFrame = function(){
//display terms at start
if(content_mc.matching_term_1._alpha < 100){
    content_mc.matching_term_1._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_1._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_2._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_2._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_2._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_3._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_3._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_3._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_4._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_4._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_4._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_5._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_5._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
//display description at start
if(content_mc.matching_term_5._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_1._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_desc_1._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_1._alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_2._alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_2._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_2._alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_3._alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_3._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_3._alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_4._alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_4._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_4._alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_5._alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_5._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    /*if(content_mc.matching_desc_5._alpha >= 100){
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
    }*/
}

//Roll over effect
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    if(eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).hitTest(this._xmouse, this._ymouse)){
        eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).mc.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else{
        eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    if(eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).hitTest(this._xmouse, this._ymouse)){
        eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).mc.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else{
        eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}

//remove the matched movieclips
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    if(eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i)._currentframe == 10){
        eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i)._y = -1000;
    }
    if(eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i)._currentframe == 10){
        eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i)._y = -1000;
    }
}

//Win Game
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    if(eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i)._currentframe == 10){
        winGame = true;
    }
    else{
        winGame = false;
        return;
    }
}
if(winGame == true){
    this.gotoAndPlay("endRound1");
}
}
```

**I have done the 3.0 like this: (but turns out the I cannot do the drag n drop)**

```
stop();
var randomPositionFrame = int(Math.random()*9)+1;
content_mc.gotoAndStop(randomPositionFrame);
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i]._alpha = 0;
       this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function():void     {
if(this._currentframe == 1){
        this.startDrag();
    }
}
);
    this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function():void {
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doMouseUp, false, 0,     true);              

);

this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+i]._alpha = 0;
        this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function():void     {
if(this._currentframe == 1){
        this.startDrag();
    }
}
);

    this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function():void {
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doMouseUp, false, 0, true);     
}
);
}

function doMouseUp($evt:MouseEvent):void
{
this.stopDrag();
}

var winGame = false;
var alphaSpeed = 20;
var mouseListener:Object = new Object();
mouseListener.onMouseDown = function () { this.isDown = true;};
mouseListener.onMouseUp = function () {
this.isDown = false;
//Game Logic Check Correct
for(var k=1; k<=5; k++){
    //term match description
    if(this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+k].mc._currentframe == 2 &&     this["content_mc.matching_term_"+k].mc._currentframe == 2){
        if(this["content_mc.matching_term_"+k]._currentframe == 1){
            this["content_mc.matching_term_"+k].gotoAndPlay(2);
            this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+k].gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
    }
    //description match term
    else if(this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+k].mc._currentframe == 2 && this["content_mc.matching_term_"+k].mc._currentframe == 2){
        if(this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+k]._currentframe == 1){
            this["content_mc.matching_term_"+k].gotoAndPlay(2);
            this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+k].gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
    }
}

};
this.Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
function myFunction(event:Event) {
//display terms at start
if(content_mc.matching_term_1._alpha < 100){
    content_mc.matching_term_1._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_1._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_2._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_2._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_2._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_3._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_3._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_3._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_4._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_4._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_4._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_5._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_5._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
//display description at start
if(content_mc.matching_term_5._alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_1._alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_desc_1._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_1._alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_2._alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_2._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_2._alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_3._alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_3._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_3._alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_4._alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_4._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_4._alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_5._alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_5._alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    /*if(content_mc.matching_desc_5._alpha >= 100){
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
    }*/
}

//Roll over effect
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    if(this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i].hitTest(mouseX, mouseY)){
        this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i].mc.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else{
        this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i].mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    if(this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+i].hitTest(mouseX, mouseY)){
        this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+i].mc.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else{
        this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+i].mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}

//remove the matched movieclips
for(var a=1; a<=5; a++){
    if(this["content_mc.matching_term_"+a]._currentframe == 10){
        this["content_mc.matching_term_"+a]._y = -1000;
    }
    if(this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+a]._currentframe == 10){
        this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+a]._y = -1000;
    }
}

//Win Game
for(var n=1; n<=5; n++){
    if(this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+n]._currentframe == 10){
        winGame = true;
    }
    else{
        winGame = false;
        return;
    }
}
if(winGame == true){
    this.gotoAndPlay("endRound1");
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I have updated my question and my work from 2.0 to 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Of course, question is not professional and nobody wants to do such uninteresting work for you. You have to read some articles for migrating from as2 to as3. I did your work, because it's easy and I had time, hope it will help and you will do it yourself next time.

```
stop();
var randomPositionFrame = int(Math.random()*9)+1;
content_mc.gotoAndStop(randomPositionFrame);
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
content_mc["matching_term_"+i].alpha = 0;
content_mc["matching_term_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function(e:MouseEvent):void     {
if(content_mc.currentFrame == 1){
        e.target.startDrag();
    }
}
);
content_mc["matching_term_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doMouseUp, false, 0,     true);
});

content_mc["matching_desc_"+i].alpha = 0;
content_mc["matching_desc_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function(e:MouseEvent):void     {
if(content_mc.currentFrame == 1){
        e.target.startDrag();
    }
}
);

content_mc["matching_desc_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function(e:MouseEvent):void {
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doMouseUp, false, 0, true);     
}
);
}

function doMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
e.target.stopDrag();
}

var winGame = false;
var alphaSpeed = 20;

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function (e:MouseEvent) { this.isDown = true;});
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function (e:MouseEvent) { this.isDown = false;});

//Game Logic Check Correct
for(var k=1; k<=5; k++){
    //term match description
    if(content_mc["matching_desc_"+k].mc.currentFrame == 2 &&     content_mc["matching_term_"+k].mc.currentFrame == 2){
        if(content_mc["matching_term_"+k].currentFrame == 1){
            content_mc["matching_term_"+k].gotoAndPlay(2);
            content_mc["matching_desc_"+k].gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
    }
    //description match term
    else if(content_mc["matching_desc_"+k].mc.currentFrame == 2 && content_mc["matching_term_"+k].mc.currentFrame == 2){
        if(content_mc["matching_desc_"+k].currentFrame == 1){
            content_mc["matching_term_"+k].gotoAndPlay(2);
            content_mc["matching_desc_"+k].gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
    }
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
function myFunction(event:Event) {
//display terms at start
if(content_mc.matching_term_1.alpha < 100){
    content_mc.matching_term_1.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_1.alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_2.alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_2.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_2.alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_3.alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_3.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_3.alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_4.alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_4.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
if(content_mc.matching_term_4.alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_term_5.alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_term_5.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
}
//display description at start
if(content_mc.matching_term_5.alpha >= 100){
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_1.alpha < 100){
        content_mc.matching_desc_1.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_1.alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_2.alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_2.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_2.alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_3.alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_3.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_3.alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_4.alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_4.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    if(content_mc.matching_desc_4.alpha >= 100){
        if(content_mc.matching_desc_5.alpha < 100){
            content_mc.matching_desc_5.alpha +=alphaSpeed;
        }
    }
    /*if(content_mc.matching_desc_5.alpha >= 100){
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
    }*/
}

//Roll over effect
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
    if(content_mc["matching_term_"+i].hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY)){
        content_mc["matching_term_"+i].mc.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else{
        content_mc["matching_term_"+i].mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    if(content_mc["matching_desc_"+i].hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY)){
        content_mc["matching_desc_"+i].mc.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else{
        content_mc["matching_desc_"+i].mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}

//remove the matched movieclips
for(var a=1; a<=5; a++){
    if(content_mc["matching_term_"+a].currentFrame == 10){
        content_mc["matching_term_"+a].y = -1000;
    }
    if(content_mc["matching_desc_"+a].currentFrame == 10){
        content_mc["matching_desc_"+a].y = -1000;
    }
}

//Win Game
for(var n=1; n<=5; n++){
    if(content_mc["matching_desc_"+n].currentFrame == 10){
        winGame = true;
    }
    else{
        winGame = false;
        return;
    }
}
if(winGame == true){
    this.gotoAndPlay("endRound1");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will study more next time before asking, really thanks!