# Drag stuffs, Actionscript 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have done a drag and match flash stuff by using Actionscipt2.0, but now I need to change it to 3.0. After I changed it, the flash can no longer drag the stuffs, can anyone please take a look at the code to see which part I was converting it wrong. Thanks.

**Actionscript 2.0 version:**

```
stop();
var randomPositionFrame = int(Math.random()*9)+1;
content_mc.gotoAndStop(randomPositionFrame);
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i)._alpha = 0;
eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).onPress = function(){
    if(this._currentframe == 1){
        this.startDrag();
    }
}
eval("content_mc.matching_term_"+i).onRelease = onMouseUp = function(){
    this.stopDrag();
}

eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i)._alpha = 0;
eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).onPress = function(){
    if(this._currentframe == 1){
        this.startDrag();
    }
}
eval("content_mc.matching_desc_"+i).onRelease = onMouseUp = function(){
    this.stopDrag();
}
}
```

**Actionscript 3.0 version:**

```
stop();
var randomPositionFrame = int(Math.random()*9)+1;
content_mc.gotoAndStop(randomPositionFrame);
for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i]._alpha = 0;
 this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function():void     {
if(this._currentframe == 1){
        this.startDrag();
    }
}
);

    this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function():void {
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doMouseUp, false, 0, true);

function doMouseUp($evt:MouseEvent):void
{
this.stopDrag();
}
}
);


this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+i]._alpha = 0;
    this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function():void     {
    if(this._currentframe == 1){
        this.startDrag();
    }
}
);

this["content_mc.matching_desc_"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function():void {
this.stopDrag();
}
);
}
```

Comment: duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374089/actionscript-2-0-to-3-0-please-give-a-hand-am-i-converting-wrong where a proper solution was found

Answer (score 0):

In your Mouse Listener you have to get the target/object from the event.  Meaning the target you applied your listener to.

Create two listener functions and apply them to your addEventListener call:

```
function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var object = e.target;
    object.startDrag();
}

function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var obj = e.target;
    obj.stopDrag();
}
```

Use addEventListener like this:

```
yourObj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
yourObj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
```

Comment: is that mean I cannot using the "this" directly? like "this.startDrag();"?

Comment: I don't believe so.  It is just a function call and the function itself thinks **this** is something else from what you think it is.  I understand your reasoning.  But in AS 3 listener functions needs to take in a parameter.  In your case a MouseEvent.  The event object itself tells you what you need to know, in this case the target.

Comment: Am I need to replce the "object" and "target" myself?

Comment: like this?  var object = e.content_mc["matching_term_"+i];

Answer (score 0):

This won't work

```
    this["content_mc.matching_term_"+i]
```

You need to talk to each object separately. So first `this` then `content_mc`.

```
    this.content_mc["matching_term_"+i]
```

Might help a little.